# Error while modifing an image using guestfish

Tags: lts, debootstrap, qcow2, libdbusmenu

I tried to modify my .qcow2 image using guestfish

```
 guestfish --rw -a parsecROI.img.qcow2
```

Welcome to guestfish, the libguestfs filesystem interactive shell for
editing virtual machine filesystems.

Type: 'help' for help on commands
      'man' to read the manual
      'quit' to quit the shell

```
run
febootstrap-supermin-helper: ext2: parent directory not found: /lib: File not found by ext2_lookup
libguestfs: error: external command failed, see earlier error messages
exit
```

after applying the update statement

```
 sudo update-guestfs-appliance
```

I got the below error. Kindly advise

```
febootstrap -v -o supermin.d --names bsdmainutils btrfs-tools cryptsetup e2fsprogs gfs-tools gfs2-tools grub-pc hfsplus iproute libaugeas0 linux-image nilfs-tools ntfs-3g ntfsprogs reiserfsprogs ufsutils util-linux vim-tiny xz-utils zfs-fuse acl attr bash binutils bzip2 coreutils cpio diffutils dosfstools file findutils gawk genisoimage grep gzip iproute jfsutils libxml2 lsof lsscsi lvm2 lzop mdadm module-init-tools parted procps psmisc scrub strace tar udev zerofree --exclude ^perl --exclude ^python --exclude ^plymouth --exclude ^linux-firmware --exclude ^kbd-misc --exclude ^file-rc
febootstrap 3.21
selected package handler: debian
packages already present:
wanted packages to download: acl adduser attr augeas-lenses base-files base-passwd bash binutils bsdmainutils bsdutils btrfs-tools busybox-initramfs bzip2 cdebconf console-setup console-tools coreutils cpio crda cryptsetup cryptsetup-bin dash debconf debianutils diffutils dmsetup dosfstools dpkg dracut e2fslibs e2fsprogs file findutils fuse gawk gcc-4.7-base genisoimage gettext-base grep grub-common grub-gfxpayload-lists grub-pc grub-pc-bin grub2-common gzip hfsplus ifupdown initramfs-tools initramfs-tools-bin initscripts insserv install-info iproute jfsutils kbd kbd-compat keyboard-configuration klibc-utils kmod kpartx libacl1 libaio1 libasprintf0c2 libattr1 libaudit-common libaudit1 libaugeas0 libblkid1 libbsd0 libbz2-1.0 libc6 libcomerr2 libconsole libcryptsetup4 libdb5.1 libdbus-1-3 libdebian-installer4 libdevmapper-event1.02.1 libdevmapper1.02.1 libdrm2 libedit2 libffi6 libfreetype6 libfuse2 libgcc1 libgcrypt11 libglib2.0-0 libgnutls26 libgpg-error0 libhfsp0 libjson0 libklibc libkmod2 liblocale-gettext-perl liblzma5 liblzo2-2 libmagic1 libmount1 libncurses5 libncursesw5 libnewt0.52 libnih-dbus1 libnih1 libnl-3-200 libnl-genl-3-200 libp11-kit0 libpam-modules libpam-modules-bin libpam0g libparted0debian1 libpcre3 libplymouth2 libpng12-0 libpopt0 libprocps0 libreadline5 libreadline6 libselinux1 libsemanage-common libsemanage1 libsepol1 libsigsegv2 libslang2 libss2 libssl1.0.0 libstdc++6 libtasn1-3 libtextwrap1 libtinfo5 libudev1 libustr-1.0-1 libuuid1 libxml2 linux-image linux-image-3.8.0-35-generic linux-image-extra-3.8.0-35-generic linux-image-generic lsb-base lsof lsscsi lvm2 lzop makedev mawk mdadm module-init-tools mount mountall multiarch-support ncurses-bin nilfs-tools ntfs-3g original-awk parted passwd procps psmisc readline-common reiserfsprogs scrub sed sensible-utils strace sysv-rc sysvinit-utils tar tzdata ucf udev ufsutils upstart util-linux vim-common vim-tiny watershed wireless-crda wireless-regdb xkb-data xz-utils zerofree zfs-fuse zlib1g
E: No downloadable files for libdrm2 version 2.4.43-0ubuntu1.1; perhaps it is a local or obsolete package?
E: No downloadable files for libplymouth2 version 0.8.8-0ubuntu6.1; perhaps it is a local or obsolete package?
febootstrap: umask 0000; cd '/tmp/febootstrap230ef4b2b88442fef2c06a27ee6a236d.tmp' && aptitude download 'acl' 'adduser' 'attr' 'augeas-lenses' 'base-files' 'base-passwd' 'bash' 'binutils' 'bsdmainutils' 'bsdutils' 'btrfs-tools' 'busybox-initramfs' 'bzip2' 'cdebconf' 'console-setup' 'console-tools' 'coreutils' 'cpio' 'crda' 'cryptsetup' 'cryptsetup-bin' 'dash' 'debconf' 'debianutils' 'diffutils' 'dmsetup' 'dosfstools' 'dpkg' 'dracut' 'e2fslibs' 'e2fsprogs' 'file' 'findutils' 'fuse' 'gawk' 'gcc-4.7-base' 'genisoimage' 'gettext-base' 'grep' 'grub-common' 'grub-gfxpayload-lists' 'grub-pc' 'grub-pc-bin' 'grub2-common' 'gzip' 'hfsplus' 'ifupdown' 'initramfs-tools' 'initramfs-tools-bin' 'initscripts' 'insserv' 'install-info' 'iproute' 'jfsutils' 'kbd' 'kbd-compat' 'keyboard-configuration' 'klibc-utils' 'kmod' 'kpartx' 'libacl1' 'libaio1' 'libasprintf0c2' 'libattr1' 'libaudit-common' 'libaudit1' 'libaugeas0' 'libblkid1' 'libbsd0' 'libbz2-1.0' 'libc6' 'libcomerr2' 'libconsole' 'libcryptsetup4' 'libdb5.1' 'libdbus-1-3' 'libdebian-installer4' 'libdevmapper-event1.02.1' 'libdevmapper1.02.1' 'libdrm2' 'libedit2' 'libffi6' 'libfreetype6' 'libfuse2' 'libgcc1' 'libgcrypt11' 'libglib2.0-0' 'libgnutls26' 'libgpg-error0' 'libhfsp0' 'libjson0' 'libklibc' 'libkmod2' 'liblocale-gettext-perl' 'liblzma5' 'liblzo2-2' 'libmagic1' 'libmount1' 'libncurses5' 'libncursesw5' 'libnewt0.52' 'libnih-dbus1' 'libnih1' 'libnl-3-200' 'libnl-genl-3-200' 'libp11-kit0' 'libpam-modules' 'libpam-modules-bin' 'libpam0g' 'libparted0debian1' 'libpcre3' 'libplymouth2' 'libpng12-0' 'libpopt0' 'libprocps0' 'libreadline5' 'libreadline6' 'libselinux1' 'libsemanage-common' 'libsemanage1' 'libsepol1' 'libsigsegv2' 'libslang2' 'libss2' 'libssl1.0.0' 'libstdc++6' 'libtasn1-3' 'libtextwrap1' 'libtinfo5' 'libudev1' 'libustr-1.0-1' 'libuuid1' 'libxml2' 'linux-image' 'linux-image-3.8.0-35-generic' 'linux-image-extra-3.8.0-35-generic' 'linux-image-generic' 'lsb-base' 'lsof' 'lsscsi' 'lvm2' 'lzop' 'makedev' 'mawk' 'mdadm' 'module-init-tools' 'mount' 'mountall' 'multiarch-support' 'ncurses-bin' 'nilfs-tools' 'ntfs-3g' 'original-awk' 'parted' 'passwd' 'procps' 'psmisc' 'readline-common' 'reiserfsprogs' 'scrub' 'sed' 'sensible-utils' 'strace' 'sysv-rc' 'sysvinit-utils' 'tar' 'tzdata' 'ucf' 'udev' 'ufsutils' 'upstart' 'util-linux' 'vim-common' 'vim-tiny' 'watershed' 'wireless-crda' 'wireless-regdb' 'xkb-data' 'xz-utils' 'zerofree' 'zfs-fuse' 'zlib1g': command failed, see earlier errors
```